# STM32F0 SWD not working VDD >2.9V

Tags: power-supply, stm32f0, swd, st-link

I made a board with a STM32F031 and connected it to the ST-Link integrated into a STM32F4-DISCOVERY.
To this point I was able to figure out, that the SWD connection works, if I supply a voltage of <2.9V via an external laboratory PSU. Anything above crashes the communication, but it returns as soon as I go down to 2.9V again.

I must confess, that I didn't do proper decoupling of the VDD pin (just 1uF + 100nF) and I will fix it accordingly to the STM32F0 Reference design for my next revision.

Also I attached an oscilloscope to the VDD line but couldn't detect any significant spikes. Also I removed all components somehow related to the VDD line (LDO, other chips), so it's basically just the STM32 with some FETs attached to its GPIOs.

Here's a log of openocd:

```
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v30 API v2 SWIM v0 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 2.887324
Info : stm32f0x.cpu: hardware has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
Polling target stm32f0x.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Examination failed, GDB will be halted. Polling again in 100ms
```

The Error, as I mentioned above, occours as soon as I go above 2.9V on my PSU. I find it odd that I have this target voltage line with ~2.89V, which is really close to my error threshold.

**Update 1:**

So I wrote a little Blinky programm, flashed it with SWD while the supply was 2.9V and then ran the chip with 5V on it's LDO resulting in VDD@3.3V, and it works. I dare to assume the Target voltage is not respected by the integrated stlink-v2 on the Discovery board. Ordered a stand alone, will update.

**Update 2:**

Stand alone STlink brought no difference, creating a second revision of the board with all caps as per reference design now works. Still, I was unable to reproduce the error with a STM32Ardurino board removing all the caps.

Comment: Not to be rude: is there a question in there? You've identified a material design issue which should be fixed before anyone else takes a crack at it. You've got no design files attached. There is nothing for us to work with.

Comment: I want to improve my odds of having an error free design in the 2nd iteration, so maybe someone experienced something funny with either stm32f031 or the stlink embedded on the stm32f4-discovery.

Comment: Then, for real, to improve your odds of a working design: copy a working design and change *ONLY* what needs to change to make it do what you need it to. If they put a cap down, you put a cap down. If it's close to the microcontroller, you put it close to the microcontroller. When  you understand why something is present in a working design, then you can think about deviating from that feature.